# Unable to iterate array of objects (undefined error)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

**PROBLEM**

How to iterate through an array of objects?

**PEN**

Codepen: [penHere](https://codepen.io/legeo/pen/MqYarz)

**CODE**

I declared this global const:

```
const items=[
    {
        name: "axe",
        image: "https://image.ibb.co/cjtHPe/if_weapon_04_707486.png",
        hit: 3
    },

    {   
        name: "redPotion", 
        image: "https://image.ibb.co/gTmU4e/if_18_Harry_Potter_Colour_Potion_Bottle_2730331.png",
        health: 40
    },

];
```

with this function I gave to characters and items random coordinates where to spawn

```
function placeCharAndItem(char, items){

    let coord = randomCoord();

    let toCheck = mapA[coord.row][coord.cell];     
    let check = toCheck.search('nonWalkable');


    while(check != -1){
        coord = randomCoord();

        toCheck = mapA[coord.row][coord.cell];     
        check= toCheck.search('nonWalkable');
    };
        place(coord, char);
        placeItem(coord, items);
};
```

and with the function below the items should be spawn in the map:

```
function placeItem(coord, items){
  items.forEach(function(obj){
       console.log(items.name);
    coord=randomCoord();  
    var charImage = $("<img>").attr("src", items.image).addClass('items');
    var row = $($("#tableGame tr")[coord.row]);
    var cell = $($("td", row)[coord.cell]);
    var tile = $(".tile", cell);  tile.prepend(charImage);
    })
};
```

The main problem is that the arrays is iterating(i think) but everytime it gives me " undefined" instead of give me the proper link to the images.

**TASK**

I've to show the image of these items in a table

**Considerations**

I read several of your answers about this topic in Stack Overflow, they recommended to use `forEach` or and old-fashon `for` loops, I hope I'm correct about this, but if I'm in the wrong way any kind of correction would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're iterating the array but not accessing the object correctly.

```
function placeItem(coord, items){
  items.forEach(function(obj){ // <- obj is what you want
    // console.log(items.name); <- items is the array
    console.log(obj.name);

    coord=randomCoord();

    // var charImage = $("<img>").attr("src", items.image).addClass('items');
    var charImage = $("<img>").attr("src", obj.image).addClass('items');

    var row = $($("#tableGame tr")[coord.row]);
    var cell = $($("td", row)[coord.cell]);
    var tile = $(".tile", cell);  
    tile.prepend(charImage);
  })
};
```

Comment: Hey Hikarunomemory, you are helping me a lot. Thank you for everything.  Your answer is right :)